# how to control Pioneer 3 DX by force sensor

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to control pioneer 3-DX by force sensor output values. If it is possible, I want to just edit the demo program which made for controlling the robot by keyboard (arrow). I read the demo program but I have no idea where I should change. Please help!
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67020/how-to-control-pioneer-3-dx-by-force-sensor/) by [Rory](https://answers.ros.org/users/5369/rory/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by force sensor output values. If you are using [p2os-vanderbilt](http://www.ros.org/wiki/p2os-vanderbilt), examine the tutorial for [setting speeds.](http://www.ros.org/wiki/p2os-vanderbilt/Tutorials/C%2B%2B%20Velocity%20Controller%20for%20P2OS%20Robots)
You should be able to set the velocity that way based on the sensor values (again, not entirely sure what you are going for here). I would not recommend you modify any existing code, but rather write your own. The link to the above tutorial should get you started with velocity programming on the p2os platform, but, if you need any more assistance, feel free to post back for coding help/email the maintainer.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2013-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0